# Trying to get XML getElementsByTagName + getAttribute call in loop to work

Tags: php, xml, dom, getelementsbytagname, getattribute

I have this overly complicated XML dump by Eatec, and sadly each menu has it's own special attribute for meals served at breakfast/lunch/dinner. I'm trying to extract the  items with their description and do a loop to show only recipe from breakfast, and so on for other menu periods.

Here's a sample slimmed down XML

```
<data>
  <menu name="location breakfast" servedate="20160626" location="food court 1" mealperiodname="Breakfast" >
    <recipes>
      <recipe id="5626935" category="HOT MORNING GRAINS" description="Oatmeal RD"> 
      </recipe>
      <recipe id="5371796" category="HOT MORNING GRAINS" description="Rice Brown RD">
      </recipe>   
    </recipes>
  </menu>
  <menu name="location lunch" servedate="20160626" location="food court 2" mealperiodname="Lunch">
     <recipes>
      <recipe id="4430587" category="SOUPS" description="Soup Tomato w/Garden Vegetables">
      </recipe>
      <recipe id="4210899" category="SOUPS" description="Soup Beef Barley w/Vegetables">
      </recipe>
    </recipes>
  </menu>
</data>
```

And I'm relatively new to PHP/XML, still trying to learn my rope here, here's what I came up with and yet not been able to keep the looped item within it's own meal period.

```
 <?php

    $menu = new DOMDocument();
    $breakfast = 'Breakfast';
    $lunch = 'Lunch';
    $menu->load("http://amphl.org/test.xml");

    // Get location name
    $menu_get = $menu->getElementsByTagName("menu");
    $location_name = $menu_get->item(0)->getAttribute("location");
    $menu_period = $menu_get->item(0)->getAttribute("name");

    // Get menus
    $recipes = $menu->getElementsByTagName("menu");
    $recipe_items = $menu->getElementsByTagName("recipe");

    // echo tests
    echo '<h3 class="location_date">'.$menu_period.'</h3>';
    echo '<h3 class="location_date">'.$location_name.'</h3>';  

    echo '<div class="meal_items">';
    // echo '<h3 class="food_name"> Breakfast </h3>';
        foreach( $recipes as $recipe )
        {
        // Get recipe name
            $recipe_type = $recipe->getAttribute("mealperiodname");  

            echo '<h3 class="location_date">'.$recipe_type.'</h3>'; 
            if ($recipe_type == $breakfast) {
                foreach( $recipe_items as $recipe_item )
                {
                    $recipe_name = $recipe_item->getAttribute("description"); 
                      echo '<p class="item_list"><a alt="" href="#">'.$recipe_name.'</a></p>';
                }

                }
            else if ($recipe_type == $lunch) {
                foreach( $recipe_items as $recipe_item )
                {
                    $recipe_name = $recipe_item->getAttribute("description"); 
                      echo '<p class="item_list"><a alt="" href="#">'.$recipe_name.'</a></p>';
                }

                }

  }
echo '</div>';
```

Instead of showing meals for breakfast and lunch in their own loop, it's loading every recipe regarding what meal period is. Am I making it too complicated ? that I got lost by my own code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you tangled yourself

```
$menu = new DOMDocument();
$breakfast = 'Breakfast';
$lunch = 'Lunch';
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$menu->load("http://amphl.org/test.xml");

foreach($menu->getElementsByTagName("menu") as $recipes) {
   echo '<h3 class="location_date">'. $recipes->getAttribute('servedate') .'</h3>' ."\n";
   echo '<h3 class="location_date">'.$recipes->getAttribute('location').'</h3>'  ."\n";  
   $recipe_type = $recipes->getAttribute("mealperiodname");
   echo '<h3 class="location_date">'.$recipe_type.'</h3>' ."\n"; 

   echo '  <div class="meal_items">' . "\n";
   foreach($recipes->getElementsByTagName("recipe") as $recipe_item) {
      echo '    <p class="item_list"><a alt="" href="#">' .
           $recipe_item->getAttribute("description") .
           '</a></p>'  ."\n";
   }        
   echo '  </div>' ."\n";
}
```

result

```
<h3 class="location_date">20160626</h3>
<h3 class="location_date">food court 1</h3>
<h3 class="location_date">Breakfast</h3>
  <div class="meal_items">
    <p class="item_list"><a alt="" href="#">Oatmeal RD</a></p>
    <p class="item_list"><a alt="" href="#">Rice Brown RD</a></p>
  </div>
<h3 class="location_date">20160626</h3>
<h3 class="location_date">food court 2</h3>
<h3 class="location_date">Lunch</h3>
  <div class="meal_items">
    <p class="item_list"><a alt="" href="#">Soup Tomato w/Garden Vegetables</a></p>
    <p class="item_list"><a alt="" href="#">Soup Beef Barley w/Vegetables</a></p>
  </div>
```

**[demo](https://eval.in/602411)**

Comment: Thanks this worked out as expected! and yes I knew i was close but got totally tangled like you said.

Answer (score 0):

It is rather confusing if you name a variable `$recipes = $menu->getElementsByTagName("menu");` but I think inside of the `foreach( $recipes as $recipe )` you want to use `$mrecipes = $recipe->getElementsByTagName('recipe')` to select on the inner `recipe` elements contained in the `menu` element.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to the DOM Api methods, you can use Xpath to fetch parts of the DOM tree. Xpath allows for conditions, so you can fetch all the menu nodes for a specific meal period.

Here is an example that outputs the information as text.

```
$mealPeriods = [
  'Breakfast',
  'Lunch'
];

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

// iterate the meal periods
foreach ($mealPeriods as $mealPeriod) {
  echo $mealPeriod, "\n=====================\n";

  // fetch all menu element nodes for a specific meal period
  $expression = "/data/menu[@mealperiodname = '$mealPeriod']";
  foreach ($xpath->evaluate($expression) as $menu) {
    echo "\n", $menu->getAttribute('location'), "\n---------------------\n";

    // iterate the recipe element nodes for a specific menu
    foreach ($xpath->evaluate('recipes/recipe', $menu) as $recipe) {
       echo '#', $recipe->getAttribute('id'), ' ';
       echo $recipe->getAttribute('description'), "\n";
    }
  } 
  echo "\n";  
}
```

Output:

```
Breakfast
=====================

food court 1
---------------------
#5626935 Oatmeal RD
#5371796 Rice Brown RD

Lunch
=====================

food court 2
---------------------
#4430587 Soup Tomato w/Garden Vegetables
#4210899 Soup Beef Barley w/Vegetables
```

Comment: I tried to run this, but the syntax error stopped at 'evaluate($expression)'